# How to have a format string with "start of week" and "end of week"

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to take a date object and format it so that the output result is something like this:

```
2015: 23 - 30 July
```

The format string would be something like this:

```
YYYY: ii - jj MMMM
```

But what do I put in for `ii` and `jj`? `ii` should be something that will evaluate to the day which is at the start of the current week, and `jj` will evaluate to the day which is at the end of the current week.

My current code:

```
console.log(moment().format('YYYY: ii - jj MMMM'));
```

Comment: Which day you want to consider as start of week? In some demographies, Monday is the first day of week, while javascript's Date object considers Sunday as start of week (returns 0 for Sunday when getDay() is called).

Comment: There is no *Date.prototype.format* method in ECMAScript. You may find something suitable in the [*ECMA 402 Internationalisation API*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/). Otherwise, just write a function yourself, it might be 4 or 5 lines of code and should accept a parameter for the first day of the week (Sunday and Monday are common, Saturday is used in some places, there may be others).

Comment: @RobG I'm using momentjs as the tags suggest. There is a format() method in momentjs http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: @domino_katrino whatever day moment().startOf('week') returns will do fine

Comment: Originally you had `date.format('...')`. What if the week spans two months (which will be frequent), or two years, e.g. 2015-12-27 to 2016-01-02 (presuming the weeks starts on Sunday)?

Comment: @RobG dunno, but I'd say that if you put in an answer saying it would be impossible to do in a format string given that the week could span a month or year boundary, I'd accept it

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: @AlexanderElgin I guess so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getWeekRange(date) {
    return moment(date).format('YYYY') + ': ' + moment(date).startOf('week').format('D') + ' - ' + moment().endOf('week').format('D MMMM');
}
getWeekRange(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not concatenate two strings?

```
moment().startOf('isoweek').format('YYYY: DD') + ' - ' + moment().endOf('isoweek').format('DD MMMM')
```

```html
<htm>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    document.write(moment().startOf('isoweek').format('YYYY: DD') + ' - ' + moment().endOf('isoweek').format('DD MMMM'));
  </script>
</htm>
```

Comment: If it's what I have to do, then something like this will be it, but I'd prefer a single format for a few reasons

Comment: @1800 INFORMATION `format` returns attributes of the date applied not the week that the date belongs. There is no such option (see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Comment: @AlexanderElgin well I don't necessarily disagree with you, but I'm hoping there could be some way to make a single format string work anyway